# Can't export wsEndpoint created from puppeteer browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, nodejs-server

I am trying to open a puppeteer browser upon startup and then exporting the wsEndpoint so that I may use the link to connect to the browser rather than opening a new browser every time I call the function.

Here is the code snippet in the file `app.js` that is the entry point for node.

```js
const mainFunction = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const wsEndpoint = browser.wsEndpoint()
    return wsEndpoint
}

mainFunction().then(async endpoint => {
    console.log(endpoint)
    module.exports = endpoint
})
```

upon startup, the console log above returns a link that I then export
And here is the code snippet in the utility file `equities.js`

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer")
const endpoint = require("../../app.js")
module.exports = async(symbol)=>{
  console.log(endpoint)
  const browser = await puppeteer.connect({connectWSEndpoint: endpoint})

}
```

Every time I call the function, the console log only returns an empty object meaning that the export in `app.js` failed for some reason. I tried to google a few things and tried different ways of exporting but none seem to work. Can someone help guide me? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things here seem amiss to me -- this code feels like it wasn't tested along the way, leading to multiple points of failure. Try to take smaller steps so you can isolate problems instead of accumulating them.

---

For starters, the `mainFunction` code abandons the `browser` object, creating a leaked subprocess resource can't be closed.

I'd return or store the `browser` variable along with the endpoint so someone can clean it up through a function. Or just return the `browser` and let the client code pull the endpoint out of it if they want, as well as manage and close the resource.

---

Next, the export code:

```js
mainFunction().then(async endpoint => {
    console.log(endpoint)
    module.exports = endpoint
})
```

I don't understand the motivation for this extra `then` wrapper that receives an `async` resolution function that never uses `await`. You may think Node `await`s all of this code, then sets the `module.exports` value before the client file's `require` runs synchronously. That's [not the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), which can be determined with a simpler piece of code:

app.js (in the same folder throughout this post for convenience):

```js
const mainFunction = async () => 42;

mainFunction().then(async endpoint => {
    console.log("endpoint":, endpoint)
    module.exports = endpoint
})
```

index.js:

```js
const endpoint = require("./app");

console.log("imported:", endpoint);
```

`node index` gives me:

```
imported: {}
endpoint: 42
```

The promise resolved after the `require`, which synchronously brought in the default blank object `module.exports` -- probably not what you expected.

If you have async code, it has to stay async forever, including exports and imports. Try exporting the promise directly, then `await`ing it in the client:

app.js:

```js
const mainFunction = async () => 42;
module.exports = mainFunction;
```

index.js:

```js
const getEndpoint = require("./app");

getEndpoint().then(endpoint => console.log("imported:", endpoint));
```

Running `node index` gives me: `imported: 42`.

---

The client code in `equities.js` looks more reasonable because it exports a promise synchronously, but it's going to have to `await` the `endpoint` promise it imported anywhere it uses it.

Also, Puppeteer throws on `puppeteer.connect({connectWSEndpoint: endpoint})`, `Error: Exactly one of browserWSEndpoint, browserURL or transport must be passed to puppeteer.connect`. I'll leave that up to you to work out based on your goals.

Here's a rewrite sketch that fixes the promise problems, but is only a proof of concept which will need tweaks to do whatever you're trying to do:

app.js:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const browserPromise = puppeteer.launch();

const endpointPromise = browserPromise
  .then(browser => browser.wsEndpoint())
;

module.exports = {browserPromise, endpointPromise};
```

equities.js:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const {browserPromise, endpointPromise} = require("./app");

module.exports = async symbol => {
  const endpoint = await endpointPromise;
  console.log(endpoint);
  //const browser = await puppeteer.connect({connectWSEndpoint: endpoint}) // FIXME
  const browser = await browserPromise;
  await browser.close();
};
```

index.js:

```
const equitiesFn = require("./equities");

(async () => {
  await equitiesFn();
})();
```

Run `node index` and you should see the ws printed.

Note that you can wrap the exported promises in functions or as part of an object which is a layer of abstraction more typical for the interface of a library if you want. But this doesn't change the fundamental asynchrony. The client will call the exported functions and await the endpoint and/or browser promises through that extra layer of indirection,

```js
require("./app").getBrowser().then(browser => /* */);
```

versus

```js
require("./app").browserPromise.then(browser => /* */);
```

If you don't want to expose the browser object, that's fine, but I'd suggest exposing a function that closes the underlying browser so you can get a clean exit, e.g.

app.js:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const browserPromise = puppeteer.launch();

const closeBrowser = () => 
  browserPromise.then(browser => browser.close())
;

module.exports = {closeBrowser};
```

index.js:

```js
require("./app")
  .closeBrowser()
  .then(() => console.log("closed"))
;
```

Comment: ahh i just realized i gave the wrong options object into the connect function of puppeteer.    
browser.wsEndpoint() returns a string that I thought I can just store into a variable and then export out of the module. The string is the only thing I needed and I was confused as to why it won't export out. But thank you for your answer! Im quite new to javascipt so I am not quite understand the main purpose of synchronous and asynchronous code. Again, thank you so much for you answer!